# Highcharts tooltip arrow position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I'm trying to modify the Highcharts tooltip for a stacked column graph so that the little arrow on the tooltip points to the middle of the bar. I know I can use the `positioner` callback to change the position of the tooltip but it seems like the arrow always points to the top of the bar no matter what its position is. See my fiddle for what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/4dy46vfx/1/.

Below is a crude screenshot of what I'm after:

[image]

Is there any way to change the position of the tooltip arrow?

Comment: I don't get it. In the Fiddle the Arrow always points at the middle of the Bar. What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Let us know how it should be printed per each point

Comment: Sorry linked the wrong fiddle. I updated the question.

Comment: Thanks for fiddle, but let us know how it should be printed, please prepare a mockups

Comment: @SebastianBochan I updated the question.

Comment: So you need to move tooltip lower? Your screenshot is mockup how it should be printed or how is?

Comment: The screenshot is what I want. Notice that the arrow is pointing to the middle of the bar, not the top.

Answer (score 0):

With disabled `tooltip.animation` property, you can calculate `anchorY` in a wrap of `updatePosition` method:

```
(function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.Tooltip.prototype, 'updatePosition', function(proceed, point) {
        proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

        this.label.attr({
            anchorY: point.plotY + point.h / 2 + this.chart.plotTop
        });
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/91tfrL45/

With the animation enabled, it is necessary to override that method:

```
Highcharts.Tooltip.prototype.updatePosition = function(point) {
    var chart = this.chart,
        label = this.getLabel(),
        pos = (this.options.positioner || this.getPosition).call(
            this,
            label.width,
            label.height,
            point
        ),
        anchorX = point.plotX + chart.plotLeft,
        anchorY = point.plotY + point.h / 2 + chart.plotTop,
        pad;

    // Set the renderer size dynamically to prevent document size to change
    if (this.outside) {
        pad = (this.options.borderWidth || 0) + 2 * this.distance;
        this.renderer.setSize(
            label.width + pad,
            label.height + pad,
            false
        );
        anchorX += chart.pointer.chartPosition.left - pos.x;
        anchorY += chart.pointer.chartPosition.top - pos.y;
    }

    // do the move
    this.move(
        Math.round(pos.x),
        Math.round(pos.y || 0), // can be undefined (#3977)
        anchorX,
        anchorY
    );
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w1qomy0x/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.animation

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts

Comment: you will have to fix the container's width, othewise the tooltip will drift left and right depending on the width of the container.

Comment: Hi @Francisco Marão, Yes, you are right, but it is enough to correct the calculation of `plotX` variable: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/91tfrL45/

Comment: @ppotaczek live demo isn't working. i have to do similar and wanted to change the column range ending edge to arrow to display the upwards and downwards, can you please check the live demo

Comment: Hi @Umair Anwaar, the live example works fine. Please create a new SO question with a detailed description of the problem.

Comment: @ppotaczek I have tried multiple times and an error is logging in to the console of jsfiddle. Highchart is not define. kindly verify

Comment: I have tested this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/91tfrL45/ and it works fine. Please add more information about the problem.